# Enter text to input nested in an iframe with watir-webdriver

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm trying to automatically enter text to an input field that is nested within an iframe using Watir.

This is what I'm using to try and access the iframe

`fr = b.frame(:index => 0)
fr.text.include? 'Remember My Sign-In ID'`

This is returning false.
Also if I try to output `fr.text` it is just an empty string.

I've also created a fiddle of the HTML I'm trying to run this against.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x4Uc5/)

Or you can hit the actual site [here](https://store.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/#!/en-us/home/main).

I'm trying to access the iframe by index because there is no ID or classes specified.

`<iframe height="auto" frameborder="0" src="https://auth.api.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/2.0/oauth/auth…rtainmentnetwork.com/shared/html/signinRedirect_SSOAuth.html" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">`

Comment: What is the problem? `located=false` just means that you have not tried to do anything with the frame yet.

Comment: Ah; didn't realize that.  I've updated the body of the question.  Basically once I try to grab the iframe that way and then try to access the text fr.text (or any element of the iframe for that matter) there is nothing there.  Which makes me believe it is not accessing the correct iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Locating the right frame**

The first problem is that you are looking in the wrong frame. There are actually 4 frames on the page (assuming you have clicked the Sign In link).

To avoid locating the element by index, you should also consider the attributes of elements around iframe:

```
<div class="_modal_content close-this-modal" id="_modal_content" tabindex="998">
  <div class="modal modal-iframe" tabindex="1000">
    <h1></h1>
    <div style="height: 638px;" class="modal-iframe-wrapper">
      <iframe marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="removed.html" frameborder="0" height="auto">
```

As you can seen in this html, the frame is the first frame in the "_modal_content" div tag. Therefore, you can find the frame with:

```
fr = b.div(:id => '_modal_content').frame
```

**Getting text of a frame**

The second problem is that the `text` method returns a blank string for frame elements. I do not remember if it has always been like this, but it seems that you need to check the text of a specific element in the frame (rather than the frame itself). The easiest way to do this is to get the first element, which is the html element.

```
fr.element.text.include? 'Remember My Sign-In ID'
#=> true
```

Comment: Thank you! Just what I was looking for. This is my first time using Watir and the docs aren't all that detailed :)